Why does radical membership over $\mathbb C$ imply radical membership over $\mathbb Q$?
Let $n \in \mathbb N$, $R_1:=\mathbb Q [x_1,...,x_n]$, $R_2:=\mathbb C [x_1,...,x_n]$, and suppose $I_1 \subset R_1$ is an ideal generated by say $f_1,...,f_m \in R_1$, for some $m \in \mathbb N$. Let $I_2 \subset R_2$ be the ideal generated by $f_1,...,f_m$.
It is clear that $a \in \sqrt{I_1}$ implies $a \in \sqrt{I_2}$.
Why does it hold that $a \in \sqrt{I_2}\cap R_1$ implies $a \in \sqrt{I_1}$?
Thank you.

Another way to see this is to note that $R_1 \to R_2$ splits as a map of $R_1$-modules since $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{C}$ splits.  Any time you have a split (or more generally, universally injective aka pure) extension, one automatically has that $J R_2 \cap R_1 = J$ for any ideal $J \subseteq R_1$ by a quick chase.

First, $I_2\cap R_1=I_1$: if $h\in I_2\cap R_1$, we have $h=\sum_if_ig_i$ for some polynomials $g_i\in R_2$, thus we can write
$$h=\sum_{i,j}\alpha_{i,j}f_im_{i,j}$$
where $\alpha_{i,j}\in\mathbb C$ and $m_{i,j}$ are monomials. Expanding both sides as linear combinations of monomials, we see that the $\alpha_{i,j}$’s satisfy a linear system with rational coefficients; since the system is solvable, it has a rational solution, hence we may assume $\alpha_{i,j}\in\mathbb Q$. This shows $h\in I_1$.
Now, $a\in\sqrt{I_2}\cap R_1$ means that $a^k\in I_2$ for some $k\ge1$, thus $a^k\in I_1$ by the first part, i.e., $a\in\sqrt{I_1}$.
